# How to construct maven ear resource

Tags: maven, web, module, ear

When launching the command mvn install, maven still in error because the web modile is not existing yet.
Does you have to make install on the web module before?

Comment: You don't have given any information about your directory structure, your pom files which exact command you have used? Have you used it on plain command line? Furthermore without any error output ? What should we guess?

Comment: In more detail : when i issue this command on the ear project : mvn install, i get this error : "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:3.0.1:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project myProject-Ear: Artifact[war:myProject-Web] is not a dependency of the project

Comment: Without the full pom I can't really help but it looks you don't have defined the war as a dependency of the EAR module...

Comment: Following your comment, i put the web module as a dependency in the  ear pom this time got this error : Could not resolve dependencies for project myProject-Ear:ear: Could not find artifact myProject-Web:war

Answer (score -1):

**There is the latest version of the ear pom used :**

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject-Ear</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>myProjectEar</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <applicationName>myProject</applicationName>
                    <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
                    <version>7</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>myProject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myProject-Web</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>myProject-Web</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myProject-Web</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>`

Comment: Why haven't you added this to the original post?

Comment: Apart from that is the war module installed in your local cache? Or do you have a multi module build ? Can you show the directory structure of your projects? Furthermore remove the complete `<configuration>..</configuration>` part in maven-ear-plugin ...just to eliminate other things first...